# Get several thumbnails for several video inputs with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command, scale, thumbnails

I want to get different thumbnails for different videos but in a unique command. I don't want to execute an ffmpeg command more than once.

I want to do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video0.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 -filter scale=128:-1 out
```

But taking several videos and getting several outputs. One for each video. Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video0.mp4 -i video1.mp4 video2.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 -filter scale=128:-1 out0.png out1.png out2.png
```

Is there a way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input0.mp4 -ss 00:01:23 input1.mp4 -ss 60 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=128:-1[v0];[1]scale=128:-1[v1];[2]scale=128:-1[v2]" -map "[v0]" -frames:v 1 output0.jpg -map "[v1]" -frames:v 1 output1.jpg -map "[v2]" -frames:v 1 output2.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this